# css clip text with moving background

Tags: html, css

I'm really a newbie when it comes to CSS - but I saw this cool effect with using the text as a mask for the background. I got it working just fine but have set my mind on trying to animate the background to continuously slide to the left. I just can't make it work.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 12rem;
  color: transparent;
  background-image: url(people.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  animation: slide_background 15s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes slide_background {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>PEOPLE</h1>
```

it slides alright... but so does the text mask.

[image: sliding.. just sliding]

How do keep the text stationary while the background slides to the side?

Comment: you need to animate the background-position not translate the whole element

Comment: @TemaniAfif how do I do that?

Comment: exactly like you are doing but instead of transform you use background-position

Comment: update your code to show it so we can see why it's not working

Comment: @TemaniAfif thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

change it to this:

```css
@keyframes slide_background {
  from {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
  }
  to { 
    background-position: 100% 0px;
  }
}
```

Now it's working! Thanks @Temani Afif for point out what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For infos: you may also use mix-blend-mode and text-indent for the animation

```css
h1 {
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 12rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
  animation: slide_background 15s linear infinite;
}
h1:before {
  content: "";
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-c-640-480-10.jpg);

  background-size: cover;
}
@keyframes slide_background {
  from {
    text-indent: 0;
  }
  to {
    text-indent: -100vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>PEOPLE</h1>
```